# Instance Variable

Tags: c#

Please consider code below. Each time I run the code, output will be always 0 and 3. I am sure it has something to do with single instance but didn't have any explanation why this is happening. It will be great if you can help me understand this. Thank you for your help.

Is this happening because variable points to a different location in heap each time we initialize it ?

```
 public class Helper
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    public List<int> GetList
    {
        get
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
    public async Task<bool> Process()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        //sleep this thread for 6 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        //When I debug, both of the thread adds into the list 
        //but first thread always have zero element on this list, if it adds to the list then where it is getting lost ?
        //not sure why ? Has to do something with the variable below _confighelper
        //but why it behaves likes this ? what would be the best explanation?
        //where this variable is getting lost ?
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        return true;
    }
}
public class RunOp
{
    //Has to do something with single instance
    Helper _configHelper;
    public async Task Run()
    {
        _configHelper = new Helper();
        var val = await _configHelper.Process();
        Console.WriteLine(_configHelper.GetList.Count);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunOp op = new RunOp();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await op.Run();
        });

        Thread.Sleep(4000);

        //Start another thread after 4 seconds
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await op.Run();
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: At the simplest, the reference of `_configHelper` is being changed while the first task is blocked, and the values it adds are placed in a reference it immediately loses. The first Task finishes it's work and prints while the second Task is blocked, so you get an output of 0. The second Task finally finishes and you get the expected output of 3.

Comment: Don't use Thread.Sleep in asynchronous programming. Doesn't really make sense to do that

Comment: Also don't use Task.Factory.StartNew in async programming. Another thing that doesn't make sense. Task.Run would be an improvement on that

Comment: Also **upvote**, i'm happy to see a new contributor adding a minimal complete verifiable example

Comment: @JonathonChase. Thank you. "Adds are placed in a reference it immediately loses" -  that answers my question.

Comment: @JoePhillips. Thank you.I was not aware that Task.Run was an improvement over startnew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple case of thread safety, and this is **not** thread safe

The problem is `RunOp` has an internal `Helper`, which gets overwritten and showing (what seems) inconsistent results because of the thread sleeps and delays.

Here is a thread safe version

```
public class RunOp
{

   private SemaphoreSlim slim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
   //Has to do something with single instance
   Helper _configHelper;
   public async Task Run()
   {
      await slim.WaitAsync();
      _configHelper = new Helper();
      var val = await _configHelper.Process();
      Console.WriteLine(_configHelper.GetList.Count);
      slim.Release();
   }

   // or

   public async Task Run()
   {
      Helper configHelper = new Helper();
      var val = await configHelper.Process();
      Console.WriteLine(configHelper.GetList.Count);
   }
}
```

I know this is only an academic problem, but this really should be refactored and thought through again